# Importing multiple files at once in matlab

Tags: matlab, import

thank you very much for reading this;

**Problem**: I have a question regarding importing in Matlab. I am trying to design a wind turbine. To do this I need to read many different text files containing the x and y coordinates defining the shape of the airfoil (all text files come in a folder) and analyse each one in turn.

My first try was

```
%% Reading the datafile 
%Opening the filename in the format given to us by UIUC 
fid=fopen('Filename',r);

%Skipping over the first lines (asterisk)
fscanf(fid,'%*s %*s %*s \n %*s %*s ',[1,5]);

%Reading over the Values of the columns
data=fscanf(fid,'%f %f  \n',[2, inf]);

%Extracting the different types of data from the datafile
x=data(1,:);
y=data(2,:);
```

Such code has two problems:

The first problem is the fact that there is a variable number of words that i need to remove in the first column

Question 1: Is there a way to remove just the first column of data from the database or would I have to delete all the values?

The second problem is that I have 1550 tables to look at and changing the filename 1550 times will be very tedious and time-consuming.

Question 2: Is there a way of opening all the files from the folder, one at a time, in one go?

Comment: Could you add a couple lines of one file, and show what you need to remove and keep?

Comment: won't your filenames all be something like table_num_1234? Then you can construct them all automatically...

Comment: Please ask a single question in each question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to read tabular files is to use `readtable`. For example, if you know your file has 2 header lines that you want to skip, then you can simply run

```
t = readtable('my_file', 'HeaderLines', 2);
```

This does, however, mean you are working with a table and not with a MATLAB array. If you prefer to keep an array, you can simply pass the table through `table2array` (example below).

In terms of dealing with lots of files, suppose your working directory has the following files:

```
a1.txt   a3.txt   b1.txt   ...
a2.txt   a4.txt   b2.txt
```

You should first get an array that contains all the filenames and then iterate over this array. One way to do this would be as follows.

```
all_files = dir('*.txt') % Use a suitable glob to match your filenames
for i = 1:length(all_files)
    data = table2array(readtable(all_files(i).name, 'HeaderLines', 2);
    % do stuff
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to read the files manually:

```
all_files = dir('*.txt') % Use a suitable glob to match your filenames
for i = 1:length(all_files)
    fid = fopen(all_files(i).name, 'r');
    % do stuff
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Note that the code assumes that all the data files have the same format.